# Перемножение столбцов матрицы - комбинации

Tags: массивы, fortran, комбинаторика

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, пожалуйста, со следующим вопросом. У меня есть матрица размерности M строк, N столбцов. Мне нужно взять любой элемент первого столбца, умножить его на любой элемент второго столбца, это всё умножить на любой элемент третьего столбца и по такому принципу вплоть до N-го столбца, таким образом перебирая все возможные комбинации. Число комбинаций будет равно M в степени N. Мне нужно осуществить это в Fortrane, люди предлагают рекурсию, но я не очень понимаю, как это сделать. Натолкните, пожалуйста, на верную идею.

Comment: Не знаю, как в новых фортранах, но в старых (до f77) рекурсии не было. Итерации. И массив (вектор) размера N, хранящий текущие индексы элементов столбцов (если N заранее не известно. Если известно, можно расписать N вложенных циклов)

Comment: Я пишу в программе Geany и пользуюсь 90-м Fortranом. Проблема в том, что N может быть очень большим и писать 50, а то и 100 вложенных циклов как то не вариант. Не подскажете, как в итерациями осуществить весь перебор, ведь очень много комбинаций получается. Единственное до чего я додумалась:
do i = 1, 2
do j = 1, 2
do k = 1, 2
a2(i,j) = matrix(i,1)*matrix(j,2)
a3(i,j,k) = a2(i,j)*matrix(k,3)
.............
do l = 4, число столбцов
a4(i,j,k,...) = a3(i,j,k)*matrix(...,4)
a2 = a3
a3 = a4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насчёт рекурсии в f90 -- извиняюсь. Оно там уже есть. С ней проще, а то, что я предлагал -- просто пути обхода её отсутствия.

```
real(8) :: mat(4,4), p(4**4)
Read(5,*) ((mat(i, j), j=1,4), i=1,4)
Do I=1,4
Write(6, FMT='(4F6.2)') (mat(i, j), j=1,4)
End Do
ip = 1
Call A(mat, 4, 4, p, 1, ip)
Write(6, Fmt='(I5 F15.4)') (i,p(i), i=1, ip-1)
End
recursive subroutine A(mat, m, n, p, icolumn, ip)
Integer(4) :: n
Real(8):: mat(m,n), p(m**n)
If (icolumn > 1) oldp = p(ip)
Do I=1, m
    If (icolumn == 1) Then
        p(ip) = mat(i, 1)
    Else
        p(ip) = oldp * mat(i, icolumn)
    End If
    If (icolumn == n) Then
        ip = ip + 1
    Else
        call A(mat, m, n, p, icolumn+1, ip)
    End If
End Do
End
```

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо за помощь, Вы меня очень выручили

Comment: @Danaida был Ваш вопрос в почте, а здесь я его не вижу. Но отвечу. В программе -- бяка, перепутаны немного строки и столбцы. Ответ поправлен. Сравните со старым вариантом. Исправлен ввод (что некритично) и в подпрограмме переставлены индексы строк и столбцов местами. Приношу глубочайшие извинения.

Comment: Еще раз огромное спасибо за столь большое внимание к моему вопросу! Я когда комментарий написала, начала экспериментировать со строками и столбцами, и программа стала правильно считать.

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, а нельзя ли как-то оптимизировать программу с учётом следующих условий: имеется два массива F (u/En (3)), 3) и En (3). Есть одно значение-фильтр u, такое, что каждый элемент массива En должен укладываться в u (u/En (3)) раз, например, если u = 4, а первый элемент массива En равен 0,2, то 4/0,2 = 20 раз.
 
    do i = 1, 20
    F1,1*F1,2*Fi,3

По идее далее необходимо взять

    do i = 1, (u/ En (3))-1 
    do j = 1,  (u/ En (2)) (20 - 1=19; 19*0,2 = 3,8

Т.е. остаётся 0,2, и если второй элемент массива En равен 0,1 (по убыванию), то 2 значения может поместиться в 4. )